# Way to find real roots in 5th polynomial equation which some constant is 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

My equation is like this:
`A x**5 + B x**4 + C x**3 +  D x**2 + E[i][j] x + F[i][j] = 0`

I want to find real roots. Constant E and F are matrix (2D array) size 80x100. My guessing code for solution of this problem is:

```
p = [A, B, C, D, E[i][j], F[i][j]]
u_cr2 = np.roots(p)
u_cr2 = u_cr2[np.isreal(u_cr2)]
print(u_cr2)
```

If I exchange `[i][j]` with first elements of matrix `[0][0]` I will get the real root for that first element of the matrix. So that tells me that the logic for this problem is pretty much okay. But how I to iterative this problem to get full solution, to get 2D array of real roots size 80x100? It doesn't works if I leave code like this.

Comment: Please provide a sample input for `A`-`F`. Also, imports are part of the code, as is indenting.

Comment: Input for A-D are just simple numbers, but for E and F are numbers generated in 2D array (matrix size 80x100). They are all floats. Yes, this is a part of the code for this part of the problem, for finding real roots of this polynomial. p and u_cr2 are properly defined in the place up in code.

Comment: So, `E` and  `F` are numpy arrays of the same shape `n x m`, and the expected output should be a numpy array `n x m x 6`?

Comment: Yes yes, 2D array with same shape. Expected output should be 2D array of the same dimensions like E and F (80x100). Why x 6? This polynomial on 5th degree has five roots for each element of the arrays, but i wanna to have output of just one, one real roots. Because other four roots are complex numbers.

Comment: Right, I meant `n x m x 5`. So, why would you assume that exactly one real root exists? Obviously, (1, -3, -5, 15, 4, -12) has five real roots. You might also be interested in the [np.polynomial.Polynomial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.classes.html) class that will make your life way easier. It even has a `p.roots()` function to return all roots, then you can filter out all complex roots.